# Why are my Firebase Firestore Security Rules allowing a .set() operation on an existing document, but the .set() has missing fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, firebase-security

This is my first question asked on stackoverflow, so please let me know if I am missing some aspect of the question that is preferred or required.

My goal is to understand why the mocha test shown below is passing when the created document is missing fields required by the firestore rules listed below.

Mocha Test Code  (Note that the project ID is checked and working but omitted here)

```
const assert = require("assert");
const firebase = require("@firebase/rules-unit-testing");
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin");
const { debug } = require("console");

const MY_PROJECT_ID = "####";

const myID = "user_abc";
const theirID = "user_def";

const myAuth = {uid: myID, email: "abc@gmail.com"};
const theirAuth = {uid: theirID};

function getFirestore(auth) {
    return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: auth}).firestore();
}


function getAdminFirestore() {
    return firebase.initializeAdminApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID}).firestore();
}


beforeEach(async ()=>{
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId:MY_PROJECT_ID});
});


describe("Our Social App", () => {

    it("Can overwrite an existing post with allowed fields", async()=>{
        const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
        const admin = getAdminFirestore();
        await admin.doc(postPath).set({authorID:myID, content:"content", 
                                       visibility:"private",
                                       headline:"headline"});

        const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
        const docRef = db.doc(postPath);
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(docRef.set({}));
    });

});

after(async ()=>{
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId:MY_PROJECT_ID});
});
```

Firestore Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function documentFieldsCheckOut(requiredFields, allowedFields){
      let requiredAndAllowed = requiredFields.concat(allowedFields);
      return request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(requiredFields) &&
             request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(requiredAndAllowed);
    }

    function updateHasOnlyAllowedFields(allowedFields){
      return debug(request.resource.data.keys()).hasOnly(allowedFields);
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /posts/{postID} {
   
      allow update: if ((resource.data.authorID == request.auth.uid) || userIsModerator()) 
                        && updateHasOnlyAllowedFields(["visibility", "content"]);
      
      allow create: if (request.resource.data.authorID == request.auth.uid) &&
                        documentFieldsCheckOut(["authorID", "content", "visibility", "headline"], 
                                                ["photo", "location", "tags"]);
    }

 }
}
```

Note: Commenting out `await admin.doc(postPath).set({authorID:myID, content:"content",  visibility:"private", headline:"headline"});` causes the test to fail as expected.
Additionally, changing the .set to .update in `await firebase.assertSucceeds(docRef.set({}));` also causes the test to fail as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're asking why this call succeeds:

```
const admin = getAdminFirestore();
admin.doc(postPath).set({authorID:myID, content:"content", 
                                   visibility:"private",
                                   headline:"headline"});
```

Calls using administrative privileges bypass the security rules of your database. So no matter what your security rules, this call will not be rejected by them.

---

The second write operation is different:

```
const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
const docRef = db.doc(postPath);
docRef.set({})
```

This time you're going though a non-admin ref as far as I can see, which means the write will have to adhere to the security rules to be accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!  
The question was why the write operation `docRef.set({})` succeeds, when the security rule below should deny the write operation. 
` allow create: if  documentFieldsCheckOut(["authorID", "content", "visibility", "headline"], "photo", "location", "tags"]);`

Performing the same .docRef.set({}) operation without first creating the document with the administrative access fails.  In other words, it looks like the rules are allowing an "overwrite" of existing data with .set() that bypasses the create rule, however I bet I am missing something!

Comment: You might want to clarify your question, as I'm still having a hard time understanding why you think the second write should be rejected in that case.

Comment: Thank you for asking me to review my question!  After reducing the code further and running more tests, I discovered that I incorrectly thought that .set() method always counted as a create in Firestore Rules.  However, it appears that it is counted as an "update" method when the document exists before the .set().  Since I granted permission in the rules to allow updates that do not have required fields, a user could potentially "update" their document to a blank document :D  Please let me know if this is an incorrect conclusion, and thank you again for your help!!!